# How can I update the aspect ratio of a linked image when update links in a PowerPoint presentation?

Tags: images, microsoft-powerpoint, links

If I add an image to PowerPoint via `Insert -> Pictures -> Link to file` or `Insert -> Pictures -> Insert and Link` the aspect ratio is correct. The height and width scale are both 100% and the aspect ratio is locked.

[image] [image]

Then I edit the image externally and change the aspect ratio (e.g. make the image narrower).

If I now update the link, the image becomes distorted in PowerPoint as it tries to fit the updated narrow image in a frame that is sized for the original wider image.
This changes the scale width, eventhough the aspect ratio is locked.

[image]

How can I let it update without affecting the scale percentages and letting PowerPoint assume the aspect ratio of the image file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't; PowerPoint is going to replace the "new" image in the same position and size as the original, so if the new image is of a different aspect ratio, it'll become distorted.

You can manually (or perhaps with a bit of code) change the scaleheight and scalewidth to 100%, but that will change the image positioning relative to the slide.

Comment: `*`sigh`*` what an *amazing* program...

Comment: Indeed. It's been a long time since I worked with other programs (DTP for example) that handled linked graphics; are there some that handle this kind of thing more gracefully?  And if so, which ones and how do they deal with changing aspect ratios? Automatically fitting the new image within the bounds defined by the original linked image, that wouldn't be so difficult. Then some sort of link properties setting that lets the user choose whether to align the new image to top/middle/bottom etc?

Comment: I don't have experience with other [WYSIWYG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WYSIWYG) applications than powerpoint. However, when I was in an environment where I could use [LaTeX](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX)/[Beamer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beamer_(LaTeX)) I loved how I could define that an image at a certain path should be included that should take up X percent of the text/page-width/height, be placed at the top/middle/bottom and forget about it. Then I could just work on the images (graphs, charts, etc...) and they would update on the slide.

Comment: That's a very useful feature. It would be theoretically possible to do something like this in PowerPoint via an add-in, except that there's no way the add-in could be notified that the image has been updated and needs to be rescaled. Pity.

Comment: in the meantime I found that Word *does* handle this gracefully with the `INCLUDEPICTURE` field code together with the `\x \y` options.